# Log in through active directory

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I want to create LogIn button through Active Directory.
So i have an idea to take Name logged user(Windows) from his Domain:

```
 string Name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

and then take Group for Login above:

```
 string Group = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups.ToString(); // <---I think this is wrong ? 
 string allowedGroup = "Admins";
```

then something like:

```
if(Name == string.Empty)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Your Name in domain doesn't exist");
 }

if(Group.ToString() != allowedGroup)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("You don't have permissions to log in");
 }
else
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
 }
```

I think my 'getting group' is wrong. How can I do it? I don't know how to exactly search for one or two groups where User is assigned.
What about when user is assigned to many Groups?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the point to use windows identity to authorize login.

1) Get the windows identity of user.

2) Use Windows identity object to get the other information like name and group.
use group name to validate user request.
Hope this will help you. Please write in comment in you have any questions.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity WI =  System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        string sUserName = WI.Name;
        bool bAuthorized = false;
        string allowedGroup = "Admins";
        IdentityReferenceCollection irc = WI.Groups;
        foreach (IdentityReference ir in irc)
        {
            if(ir.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value == allowedGroup)
            {
                bAuthorized = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sUserName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Name in domain doesn't exist");
        }
        if(bAuthorized == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have permissions to log in");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
```

Comment: so in string  sGroup i have groups where user is assigned?

Comment: uh... i am confused. How it will looks like in one part?:((

Comment: Yes, string sGroup will have group name that user is assigned.

Comment: Hmm... i just tried it but it's not working. In domain i have a lot of groups and program break loop after check first of it. Second of all ir.value is not domain's name but i think this is ID or something because resault of ir.value is ex. s-1-2-3455435-435435 etc. Can you help ?

Comment: I modified the code to get the friendly name of groups. Please try this.

Comment: Yes, now i can see my Group in domain but... It doesn't work:(. I think something is wrong with this loop.Ex: I have account witch is assigned to groups: 'All', 'Admins', 'Users'. My authorized group to log in is 'Admins. Now- loop select one of goup for ex. Admins and its ok-bAuthorized = true, but then go to group called 'Users' and set bAuthorized to false- there is break and its over- always will be bAuthorized = false. Am i right ?

Comment: I think i need to list all of groups and then looking for one 'this good' group and if there is- change bAuthorized to true ?

Comment: Oh, i get new issue. "Some or all identity references could not be translated." this is because: ir.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value

Comment: ok. I got this.  foreach(IdentityReference ir in irc)  {   NTAccount accInfo = (NTAccount)ir.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                
                if (accInfo.Value != allowedGroup)
                {...  It's working :) - i wrote it in answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got this. Thanks for Pankaj.

```
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity WI = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    string sUserName = WI.Name;
    bool bAuthorized = false;
    string allowedGroup = "Admins";
    IdentityReferenceCollection irc = WI.Groups;
    foreach (IdentityReference ir in irc)
    {
      NTAccount accInfo = (NTAccount)ir.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

        if (accInfo.Value == allowedGroup)
        {
           bAuthorized = true;
           break;
        }
    }
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sUserName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your Name in domain doesn't exist");
    }
    if(bAuthorized == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You don't have permissions to log in");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
```